# Windows: is it possible to reconnect to the same instance of a named pipe

Tags: winapi, named-pipes

I have a named pipe created by CreateNamedPipe function, and a client that connects to it with CreateFile. After some communication, the client might disconnect (by calling CloseHandle).
When it tries to reconnect again, it gets ERROR_PIPE_BUSY. Is it even possible to reconnect to the same pipe without doing anything on the server end?
If not, then what should be done on the server end?

Comment: reconnect is possible. but server must call `DisconnectNamedPipe` on broken pipe instance

Comment: How can server know that the pipe is broken? Should it do some check in a loop in the background?

Comment: server must permanent read data (call ReadFile) after connect. when client close self side - read request fail with code `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE`

Comment: I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889805/is-there-any-way-to-detect-whether-client-pipes-handle-is-closed-when-using-nam) answer. Not sure, if it's my only option to detect a broken pipe as soon as it's broken.

Comment: yes, this is absolute correct answer. and the same as i say - after connect need permanent call `ReadFile` on pipe handle. after read complete - just new `ReadFile` until it fail with `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE`

Comment: You can call `PeekNamedPipe` to avoid reading from the pipe. Or for the local info, call `NtQueryInformationFile` for the [`FilePipeLocalInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_file_pipe_local_information). The local server and client ends share a common context control block (CCB) that has the `NamedPipeState`. This will be `FILE_PIPE_CLOSING_STATE` if one end is closed. This query requires a handle with read-attributes access, so it won't help with an outbound-only pipe, unless you use undocumented `NtCreateNamedPipeFile`.

Comment: Suppose, there's this case: a client has written data to pipe, then disconnected. I have a method that allows me to check if the pipe is broken, this method uses PeekNamedPipe. If there's data in the pipe, this method returns False (not broken). But the client has already disconnected. Would __NtQueryInformationFile__ help me in this case?

Comment: @RayP., yes, peeking at the pipe contents only tells you that there's data available. After you read it, the next peek will fail due to the broken pipe. And yes, the `FilePipeLocalInformation` will report the state as `FILE_PIPE_CLOSING_STATE` even if there's data in the pipe. This state is set immediately on the shared CCB when the client side is closed. FYI, remember to @ notify the recipient of a comment, e.g. @eryksun. You get notified automatically for comments on your own questions and answers, but the system doesn't necessarily notify everyone else.

Comment: @eryksun, thank you. I've implemented calls to NTQueryInformationFile and was very happy about it, until I created a named pipe with PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND. Now I get ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED when I try to call NtQueryInformationFile, because PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND is equal to GENERIC_WRITE access, so I need to somehow specify FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, when creating the pipe. Is this possible?

Comment: Files don't allow duplicating a handle to get increased access. If you can't use duplex mode, you'll have to use undocumented [`NtCreateNamedPipeFile`](https://github.com/reactos/reactos/blob/releases/0.4.8/ntoskrnl/io/iomgr/file.c#L3412) if you need to read pipe meta-data. Request `GENERIC_WRITE | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` access. Configure outbound mode by requesting `FILE_SHARE_READ` access sharing.